# django-admin: list action with modal(not intermidiate page) to bulk update model with input value

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I want to update a list of model with input values but using modal instead of intermediate page in admin, I googled a lot but I don't find any help, can someone give me some helps ?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, let's say you have a table of `data` for example, and when you click on a row to update, a modal pop up with the selected row's `data` within a form or something like that. Not sure if that's the idea behind your question.

If that's the idea, then maybe you could see this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72497387/15978450) to get the concept.

Comment: Sorry the context is django admin, i updated my question