# pass a value from bootstrap to django modal

Tags: python, django

Here i am trying to pass the value outside for loop modal using ajax

here is my template.html

```
               {% for compliance in compliance %}
                    {% complience_category compliance request.user as compliances %}
                    {% for qualification in compliances %}
                    .....
                    .....
                    <td>
                        <button data-id="{{ qualification.id }}" type="button" class="btn btn-warning margin-bottom edit-qualification">
                            edit
                        </button>
                    </td>
                    ....
                    .....
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="modal hid fade" id="modal-default">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action=" {% url 'update_qualifications' qualification.id %}"> 
                        {% csrf_token %}

                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                <h3>Update Compliance</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="inputdate_{{qualification.id}}">Expiry Date</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                            <input type="date" id="inputdate_{{qualification.id}}" name="expiry_date" value="{{qualification.expiry_date|date:'Y-m-d'}}">
                                       
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                
                                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
                            </div>


                    </form>
                </div>

                {% endfor %}
```

This is my AJAX

```
$(document).on('click','.edit-qualification',function(){
    var id = $(this).data('id');

    $.ajax({
        url:'',
        type:'POST',
        data:{
            'id':id,
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
        },
        success:function(data){
            $('#edit_modal .modal-dialog').html($('#edit_modal .modal-dialog',data));
            $('#edit_modal').modal('show');
            
        },
        error:function(){
            console.log('error')
        },
    });
});
</script>
```

Here my modal is outside of for loop

Here my problem is when i click the edit button my modal popup is not working (it means when clicking the edit button nothing works for me )

Answer (score 0):

> Here my modal is outside of for loop

From the looks of this, the modal is still inside of a `for loop`.

```
{% for compliance in compliance %}
     ...
     ...
     # your modal is here...
{% endfor %}
```

I'd suggest placing the modal outside of the `loop`.

Another thing to note is that using `Ajax` here is really unnecessary unless I'm not understanding what's your purpose for using it.

However, for the `edit button`, I'd suggest that you add two attributes; `data-toggle` and `data-target`. Example:

```
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
     edit
</button>
```

In your case, you have for the modal `div` an `id`: `id="modal-default"`. This should be assigned to your button's `data-target` attribute. `data-target="#modal-default"`.

So what you should have instead for the `edit button` is:

```
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-default" data-id="{{ qualification.id }}" type="button" class="btn btn-warning margin-bottom edit-qualification">
     edit
</button>
```

Ideally, that should work to display the modal.

As for the question of how to pass the values to the modal if a specific edit button is clicked, then I'd suggest you see this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72497387/15978450) as it might be very useful.